# Django: Tastypie filesize

Tags: django, tastypie

I may be asking something stupid, but i'm a total noob at django, so...

I have a file upload model, and i'm spitting it out via json. 
I'd like to be able to also spit out the filzesize of each file.
How would i go on about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [dehydrate](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#dehydrate) method and make something like this:

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
    photo = fields.FileField(attribute="photo")
    class Meta:
        queryset = Note.objects.all()

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['photo_size_in_bytes'] = bundle.obj.photo.size  # size in bytes 
        return bundle
```

This will add size in bytes to your json.

Comment: Sorry for the late award, i am just getting to testing this out. It works!